# Плагин для AJAX валидации формы

Tags: ajax

Посоветуйте плагин для Ajax валидации формы.
Желательно настраиваемый.
В идеале нужно чтобы не заполненный/не верно заполненные поля обводились рамкой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [jQuery plugin: Validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) - рамкой обводит и настраиваемый - [демо страница](https://jqueryvalidation.org/files/demo/)
- [...и ещё много других - выбирайте! (смотреть внизу страницы)](http://speckyboy.com/2010/06/22/50-jquery-plugins-for-form-functionality-validation-security-and-customisation/)

PS. Если искать в гугле по заголовку вопроса, то вы найдёте ответ в течение 1 минуты